# Transform quarterly data into yearly data

Tags: r

I have quarterly data and I'd like them to be yearly data. I did this so far

```r
realGDP <- zooreg(realGDP, start=as.yearqrt("1980 Q1"), 
                frequency = 4)

realGDP <- aggregate(realGDP, as.year, mean)
```

I obtain

> object 'as.year' not found

I really can't figure out how to aggregate it otherwise...
Thank you for your help

Comment: please add a sample of your data with `dput(realGDP)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you and take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `realGDP` is the zooreg object defined in the first line of code in the question then first note that `yearqtr` class internally represents a year/month as the year plus 0 for Q1, 1/4 for Q2, 2/4 for Q3 and 3/4 for Q4.  Thus the integer part of a yearqtr object is the year:

```
library(zoo)

aggregate(realGDP, as.integer, mean)
## 1980 1981 1982 
##  2.5  6.5  9.5
```

### Note

Questions should have complete reproducible input.  I have provided some this time:

```
library(zoo)
realGDP <- zooreg(1:10, start = as.yearqtr("1980 Q1"), freq = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm using the answer instead of the comments, don't have the proper permissions. It's hard to help you without seeing what your data looks like in the context of a reproducible example. Something like the below might be helpful, but again hard to know without understanding the data.

```
realGDP <- realGDP %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(year = lubridate::year(quarter)) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(value = mean(value))
```